# how to .LESS with Bootstrap *without* javascript?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

Learning .LESS here, both the javascript method and using SimpLESS to compile a .css file. I can't seem to get the SimpLESS method to work with bootstrap.

Is there something I need to do to get the bootstrap HTML file to "see" the css file compiled by SimpleLess?

Thank you!

Comment: SimpLESS has not been updated for about year and a half. Consider using [other compilers/tools](http://lesscss.org/usage/#guis-for-less).

Comment: when I downloaded and opened the installed, I was warned that I was putting my computer at a security risk..warned by the Adobe AIR application installer. This leaves me feeling I'm in un-safe territory..any comments on this?

Comment: Well, there're 10 GUI [tools](http://lesscss.org/usage/#guis-for-less), about [5 IDEs](http://lesscss.org/usage/#editors-and-plugins) with Less compilation support, and finally the reference [command line compiler itself](http://lesscss.org/usage/#command-line-usage)... Btw, I almost forgot:

Comment: Questions asking us to *recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource* are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: OK..I can respect that..thank you for observing that..

Answer (score 0):

If you also work with PHP you could try http://leafo.net/lessphp/ to compile less-files. It should work with bootstrap as well and is pretty easy to handle. I prefer it.

Comment: Well, lessphp is not compatible with recent Bootstrap versions too.